# Sum column up to the current row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, partitioning

I'm trying to sum a column up to the current row (in SQL Server). How do I do this?

```
select t1.CounterTime,
       t1.StartTime,
       t1.EndTime,
       isNull(t1.value, 0) as value1,

       -- How do I make Total1 the sum of t1.value over all previous rows?
       sum( isNull(t1.value, 0) ) over (partition by t1.CounterTime order by t1.CounterTime) as Total1

from   SomeTable t1
order by t1.CounterTime
```

But I got the `partition by` wrong...

```
╔═══╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦════════╦════════╗
║   ║      CounterTime        ║        StartTime        ║         EndTime         ║ value1 ║ Total1 ║
╠═══╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 1 ║ 2015-03-17 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-17 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-18 00:00:00.000 ║     0  ║     0  ║
║ 2 ║ 2015-03-18 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-18 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-19 00:00:00.000 ║     0  ║     0  ║
║ 3 ║ 2015-03-19 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-19 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-20 00:00:00.000 ║   422  ║   422  ║
║ 4 ║ 2015-03-20 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-20 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-21 00:00:00.000 ║   989  ║   989  ║
║ 5 ║ 2015-03-21 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-21 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-22 00:00:00.000 ║  1162  ║  1162  ║
║ 6 ║ 2015-03-22 12:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-22 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-03-23 00:00:00.000 ║   524  ║   524  ║
╚═══╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Should be:

```
╔════════╗
║ Total1 ║
╠════════╣
║     0  ║
║     0  ║
║   422  ║
║  1411  ║
║  2573  ║
║  3097  ║
╚════════╝
```

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server` are you using?

Comment: Perhaps use a correlated sub-query to do the SUM?

Comment: This might be very related, if not a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver

Comment: If you want sum of all previous rows, just remove  `partition by t1.CounterTime ` and keep `order by t1.CounterTime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this
Remove the "partition by" use only "order by"

```
select t1.CounterTime,
           t1.StartTime,
           t1.EndTime,
           isNull(t1.value, 0) as value1,

           -- How do I make Total1 the sum of t1.value over all previous rows?
           sum( isNull(t1.value, 0) ) over (order by t1.CounterTime) as Total1

    from   SomeTable t1
    order by t1.CounterTime
```

Answer (score 1):

**here it is an sample example to calculate running totals**

```
declare @t table (id int,val int)
insert into @t(id,val)values (1,0),(2,0),(3,411),(4,989),(5,1162),(6,524)

SELECT ID, val, RunningTotal = val + COALESCE(
(
  SELECT SUM(val)
    FROM @t AS i
    WHERE i.ID < o.ID), 0
)
FROM @t AS o
ORDER BY ID;
```

**IN Sql 2012**

```
SELECT ID, val, 
  RunningTotal = SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY TID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM @t
ORDER BY TID;
```

the same code can be used into your query my guess **countertime** can be used **Id's** then it will work as per result

```
select t1.CounterTime,
           t1.StartTime,
           t1.EndTime,
           isNull(t1.value, 0) as value1,
           RunningTotal = t1.value + COALESCE(
(
  SELECT SUM(value)
    FROM SomeTable AS i
    WHERE i.CounterTime < o.CounterTime), 0
)

    from   SomeTable t1
    order by t1.CounterTime
```