# How to sum the values of a column in SQL Server from the current row to the last within a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36c43/8)

I tried to sum the column `qx` in my CTE from the [current row to the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695670/sum-column-up-to-the-current-row-in-sql) creating a calculated column called `qxsum` like the following:

```
declare @idade int = 25
declare @sexo char = 'm'

;with cte as (
    select
        @idade as idade,
        @sexo as sexo,
        case when @sexo = 'm' then mor.Masculino else mor.Feminino end as qx,
        cast((sum(1.0) over (order by @idade rows between current row and unbounded following)) as float) as qxsum
     from Mortalidade as mor
     where mor.Idade = @idade

     union all

      select
          cte.idade + 1,
          cte.sexo,
          mor.qx,
          cast((sum(cte.qx) over (order by @idade rows between current row and unbounded following)) as float) as qxsum
      from cte

      outer apply (
          select
              case when cte.sexo = 'm' then mor.Masculino else mor.Feminino end as qx
          from Mortalidade as mor
          where mor.Idade = cte.Idade + 1
      ) mor

      where cte.Idade < 120
) select * from cte option (maxrecursion 0);
```

For instance, for the age 25 in the SQL Fiddle above the `qxsum` should be the sum from `qx` from the age 25 to the age 120.

But SQL Server is returning the same value lagging one row, because I am making mistakes and I don't know  which mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to order by *column* `idade` rather than by the *variable* `@idade` (whose value is the same for all rows). Also, to generate the window `sum()` for all ages that are greater or equal than the one of current row, you can just order the records by *descending* `idade` (so there is no need for a `rows` frame).

I find that is simpler to use the recursive cte to just generate the list of `idade`s, and then bring the table with `left join` in the main query.

```
declare @idade int = 25;
declare @sexo char = 'm';

with cte as (
    select @idade idade
    union all select idade + 1 from cte where idade < 120
)
select
    c.idade,
    @sexo sexo,
    case when @sexo = 'm' then m.masculino else m.feminino end as qx,
    sum(case when @sexo = 'm' then m.masculino else m.feminino end) 
        over(order by c.idade desc) qxsum
from cte c
left join mortalidade m on m.idade = c.idade
order by c.idade
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Note that you should be storing the genders on different rows rather than in columns (this would avoid the need for conditional logic).

For your sample data, **[this query yields](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03ea6ab410c306744ed87017d6da3e90)**:

```
idade | sexo | qx           | qxsum        
----: | :--- | :----------- | :------------
   25 | m    | 0.0019300000 | 28.0897400000
   26 | m    | 0.0019600000 | 28.0878100000
   27 | m    | 0.0019900000 | 28.0858500000
   28 | m    | 0.0020300000 | 28.0838600000
   29 | m    | 0.0020800000 | 28.0818300000
   30 | m    | 0.0021300000 | 28.0797500000
  ............. more rows here ............
  111 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 10.0000000000
  112 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 9.0000000000 
  113 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 8.0000000000 
  114 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 7.0000000000 
  115 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 6.0000000000 
  116 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 5.0000000000 
  117 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 4.0000000000 
  118 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 3.0000000000 
  119 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 2.0000000000 
  120 | m    | 1.0000000000 | 1.0000000000
```